# Windows VPN through non-default network interface

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I have 2 network interfaces and I'm wanting to set the first one as the default and the second as a backup.

I also want the VPN to always connect using the backup but I can't find any settings for the VPN to select a specific interface to use.

Comment: If you want to set the path traffic flows you need to configure routes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done in Windows. On the one hand, you cannot bind your VPN to a specific interface, it will just pick the one with the default gateway.

Then, even if you managed to do that, you have no policy routing (or source-based routing). In other words, if a packet comes in through the second interface (the one on which you have the VPN), there is no way to send it back through the same interface: 
the kernel, following the routes in the routing table, would send it out through the interface of the default gateway, thus making all communication impossible.